# ReinH Git Workflow

Tags: git

I am using this workflow:

http://reinh.com/blog/2009/03/02/a-git-workflow-for-agile-teams.html

where he mentions:  "First, and while in your master branch (git checkout master), pull in the most recent changes: 
git pull origin master
This should never create a merge commit because we are never working directly in master."

Whoops, I just did. I accidentally committed a few changes to a couple of files to my master (vs my topic branch). I then realized my mistake - deleted my topic branch. Now I want to get rid of my committed changes (to the master), what is the right thing to do? I have not rebased yet or pushed my changes to repo, so it is all local.

In essence, I want to pull down the latest version of the master code and just disregard everything I have done to my local master (which is really one commit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to throw it away, while you're on your master branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This command will reset your master's HEAD pointer to the previous commit.  (You could also say "HEAD~1", which means the same thing as HEAD^.)  More generally, you can also reset your master to be the same as the server's:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will work regardless of the state of master (i.e. 5 commits ahead of origin, or 30 commits behind it).  The `--hard` option in these commands means that the files in your working tree will also be reset along with the branch heads.

**Extra tips**

If you were in a similar situation where you actually wanted to keep your changes, you can always do:

```
git fetch             # This grabs changes from the server without merging them
git rebase origin
```

That will replay any work you have in master on top of the latest changes on the server.

Yet another alternative would be to create a topic branch for your work on master:

```
git checkout -b newfeature
```

Then you could switch back to master (git checkout master) and use the first command I gave to rewind master back one commit.  Remember, branches are really just convenient names for commits in your repository.  For example, `master` is just a reference to the latest commit on that branch.  You can move these references at will, and as you get more advanced with git, you'll find yourself doing it fairly often.

I also recommend you get in the habit of running `gitk --all` whenever you're playing with branches, so you can visually see exactly what you're doing.  When I was new to git, I ran this command *all the time*.  I still do...

Answer (score 1):

All your commits lost by the branch deletion are there yet in git.

You can access all of them by traversing the reflog. Take a look to

```
man git-reflog
```